# RhinoMock: two class reference, how to mock parent method?

Tags: unit-testing, parent-child

My English not good. But I think code you can understand.
I have two class, like this:      classB:classA
classA is classB parent. Now I hava two interface like this:  IclassB,IclassA.
classA have a method. like this:  classA.GetAllData(); 
I want write unit test. I want to test classB.GetData();
classB.GetData() method like this:`classB.GetData(){
return classA.GetAllData();
}`

So, I mock classA.GetAllData(). like this:`var mockAStub= MockRepository.GenerateStub<IclassA>();
var mockA = new classA(mockAStub);
mockA.stub(s=>s.....`

test method can not go to the mockA method, 
Do you know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is :

var mockAStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub();
mockAStub.Stub(s => s.GetAllData()).....

classB.GetData();

And maybe asserting the method mockAStub.GetAllData() is called like this :

mockAStub.AssertWasCalled(s => s.GetAllData());

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much! Today I changed assert method. Test result is OK.